# Can't update a record using entity framework and ninject with Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, ninject-2, ninject.web.mvc

I am using MVC3, Ninject , Ninject MVC extensions, EF 4.1

I have implemented the following repo pattern.

Repository.cs

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> AsQueryable();

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    void Delete(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;


    public Repository(IObjectContext objectContext)
    {

        _objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        //_objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _objectSet.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(where);
    }

    public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return _objectSet.Single(where);
    }

    public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return _objectSet.First(where);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {

        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {


        _objectSet.Attach(entity);

    }
}
```

Unit of Work.cs

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IObjectContext _objectContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        _objectContext = objectContext;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_objectContext != null)
        {
            _objectContext.Dispose();
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _objectContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

ObjectContext.cs

```
public interface IObjectContext : IDisposable
{
    IObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : class;
    void SaveChanges();
}

public class ObjectContextAdapter : IObjectContext
{
    readonly ObjectContext _context;

    public ObjectContextAdapter(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public IObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : class
    {

        return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have used Ninject to bind them in the IOC using the following implementation

```
 public override void Load()
    {
        Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));

        Bind<IObjectContext>().To<ObjectContextAdapter>().WithConstructorArgument("context", new MGTContainer());
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();

    }
```

The repo pattern is taken from here 
[Repo Pattern Implementation](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/)

Here is a sample use of the pattern in the controller

```
 eventRepository.Attach(model);
        unitOfWork.Commit();
```

All works fine for Inserting, Reading and Deleting records but when i call the attach i have the following error

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I have tried changing the binding to InRequestScope but this causes subsequent errors.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show the full code which throws the exception? Creating a context, calling `Attach` and `SaveChanges` doesn't cause such exception.

Comment: The context is created in the IOC binding, I have already included the call to the attach method and the unitof work commit call which will then call the submitchanges method. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: What is `model` and where does it come from? Read the exception carefully: It talks about **multiple** objects in the ObjectStateManager. Where does the at least second object with the same key come from? Your code shows only one single object called `model` at all. Another problem might be that your context doesn't get disposed after a web request. Then old objects (with same key!) from earlier requests might still be in the context, causing the exception. `InRequestScope` sounds actually good for a web app. Are you sure that you don't need to use this binding?

Comment: Hi Slauma, model is an instance of Event object passed back from the post method from the html form. It is provided as an Event object by MVC binding if you are familiar with that. I do not know where the second object comes from and i suspect the problem lies in a way i am binding the context in the IOC. Hope that helps

Comment: You can check if there are objects in the context by using `var list = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();`. If you call this at the beginning of your post action this list should always be empty, for the very first and also all subsequent requests. I suspect that the list is not empty for the second and later requests which would mean that your context doesn't get disposed after a request. I'm not familiar with Ninject, so I can't answer in detail. Try to find out how to setup `InRequestScope` lifetime correctly for `DbContext`. I think that there is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Attach is not working well. What I am doing is just

1. fetch the single record
2. copy all properties to that record and
3. commit.